# Could someone explain C++ escape character " \ " in relation to Windows file system?

Tags: c++, string, windows, escaping

I'm really confused about the escape character " \ " and its relation to the windows file system. In the following example:

```
char* fwdslash = "c:/myfolder/myfile.txt";
char* backslash = "c:\myfolder\myfile.txt";
char* dblbackslash = "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt";

std::ifstream file(fwdslash); // Works
std::ifstream file(dblbackslash); // Works
std::ifstream file(backslash); // Doesn't work
```

I get what you are doing here is escaping a special character so you can use it in this string. In no way by placing a backslash in a string literal or std::string do you actually change the string ---

---Edit: This is completely wrong, and the source of my confusion---

So it seems that the escape character is only treated by certain classes or things to mean something other than a backslash, like outputting on the console, ie., std::cout << "\hello"; will not print the backslash. In the case of ifstream (or I'm not sure if the same applies with the C fopen() version), it must be that this class or function treats backslashes as escape characters. I'm wondering, since the Windows file system uses backslashes wouldn't it make sense for it to accept the simple string with backslashes, ie., "c:\myfolder\myfile.txt" ?  Trying it this way fails.

Also, in my compiler (Visual Studio) when I include headers I can use .\ and ..\ to mean either the current folder, or the parent folder. I'm pretty sure the \ in this isn't related to the escape character, but are these forms specific to Windows, part of the C preprocessor, or part of the C or C++ language? I know that backslashes are a Windows thing, so I can't see any reason another system would expect backslashes even when using .\ and ..\

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In no way by placing a backslash in a string literal[...] do you
>   actually change the string

You do. **Compiler actually modifies literal** you wrote before embedding it into compiled program. If a backslash is found in string or character literal **while parsing source code** it **is ignored** and next character is treated specially. `\n` becomes carriage return, etc. For escaped characters without special meaning threatment is implementation defined. Usually it just means *character unchanged*.

You cannot just pass *"c:\myfolder\file.txt"* because it is not a string which will be seen by your program. Your program will see *"c:myfolderfile.txt"* instead. This is why escaped backslash has a special meaning, to allow embedding backslashes in actual string your program will see.

The solution is to either escape your backslashes, or use raw string literals (C++11 onwards):

```
const char* path = R"(c:\myfolder\file.txt)"
```

Filenames given to `#include` directive are not string literals, even if they are in form *"path\to\header"*, so substitution rules are not applied to them.

Comment: I see now, I was so dumb. That's why I was confused. I'm trying to strikethrough that part of my question but I don't know how. Maybe I should just delete it.

Comment: @Zebrafish generally you should not delete or vandalize your questions. Someone else might have same misonception that you had, and your question and answers to it can help him.

Comment: So is the .\ and ..\ C preprocessor specific?

Comment: Hang on a second, "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt" string literal ends up as with two backslashes. Why?

Comment: @Zebrafish What do you mean? If you will print it character by character, it will show single backslashes:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/afe2f2e0ad5232ae

Comment: You're right. In Visual Studio if I hover over the variable in the debugger it shows "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt" .  However the single backslash one it shows "c:myfoldermyfile.txt" . I REALLY wish it wouldn't do that, confusing as hell.

Comment: The debugger is trying to represent the string as it would appear in source code.  But it has no way to tell when the source code originally included unnecessary backslashes (quoting a character that doesn't need to be quoted) so they get left out.  While using this format is potentially confusing, it would be hard for it to represent special characters if it didn't.  Just in case you're still a little confused, note that `"myfolder"` and `"\myfolder"` are the *exact same strings*, the backslash is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3):

The single backwards slash practically escapes the next character. In order to get rid of this behavior you need to double escape it. Now for the forward slash, it is probably a compatibility issue which follows the Unix tradition.

Similar thing to this is also in the Java world. A single forward slash is treated for path separation on both Windows and Unix, while also a double backslash.

To make it more clear why single backslash doesn't work, just remember that the following String practically produces a newline, a backslash and a tab:

```
"\n\\\t"
```

i.e. in an example like:

```
""c:\my\next\file.txt"
```

would actually produce:

```
"c:my
ext

ile.txt"
```

(the double space is form feed, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C))

Comment: Yeah I found out that Windows accepts both forward slashes too. the thing I don't get is, you're opening a file, and Windows native system uses backslashes, why wouldn't you just pass it "c:\myfolder\file.txt" ?  Adding escape characters doesn't change the actual string, it just seems that certain "things" use the " \ " to mean an escape character.

Comment: @Zebrafish That doesn't make any sense. The backslash *always* escapes, because it is a property of backslashes in a string literals. It doesn't matter in which context that string literals appears. If you would loop over the single backslash string, you would notice that no backslash character appears.

Comment: @Rakete Ohhh, I see. I was totally wrong. It always escapes. So I was wrong in my question when I assumed that the backslash doesn't change the c string

Comment: PS: Windows only accepts forward slashes *sometimes*.  It is best not to get into the habit of using them, because then it will catch you by surprise when you run into a situation where they don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because when declaring a cstring literal the backslashes escape the next character, for special characters. This is so you can do newlines (\n), nulls (\0), carriage returns (\r) etc...

char* backslash = "c:**\m**yfolder **\m**yfile.txt";

Comment: I see, but the backslash doesn't change the actual string, it's just that certain things treat the backslash as an escape character for its own purposes, like cout. What I'm wondering though is that if Windows file system uses backslashes, why doesn't it simply take a string "c:\myfolder\myfile.txt"? I'm aware that the backslash escapes, but only certain things treat the backslash as an escape character. In this case it seems ifstream is treating it as an escape character.

Comment: Why do you say "the backslash doesn't change the actual string"?  I think you're confused about this.  The string `"n"` is not at all the same as the string `"\n"`; the former contains the letter n, the latter contains a newline character.

Comment: @Harry Johnston Thanks. I now see the light. I was totally wrong in saying that the backslash doesn't actually change the c string. I actually checked, I must have messed up somewhere, or am blind.