# Replace single backslash with double in a string c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to replace one backslash with two. To do that I tried using the following code

```
str = "d:\test\text.txt"
str.replace("\\","\\\\");
```

The code does not work. Whole idea is to pass `str` to `deletefile` function, which requires double blackslash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could someone explain C++ escape character " \ " in relation to Windows file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021357/could-someone-explain-c-escape-character-in-relation-to-windows-file-sys)

Comment: Your problem is not actually duplicating backslashes. There are no backslashes in `str`. `\t` is a tab character, not a backslash followed by the letter `t`. The linked duplicate explains the issue.

Comment: `str = "d:\test\text.txt"` -- There are no backslashes in the string.  You have `d` `:` <tab> `e` `s` `t` <tab> `e` `x` `t` `.` `t` `x` `t`.

Comment: Tried the following but still not worked. 

str.replace(str.begin(), str.end(), "\t","\\");

Answer (score 1):

since c++11, you may try using regex

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto s = std::string(R"(\tmp\)");
    s = std::regex_replace(s, std::regex(R"(\\)"), R"(\\)");

    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

A bit overkill, but does the trick is you want a "quick" sollution

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

First line: you forgot to double the \ in the literal string. 
It happens that \t is a valid escape representing the tab character, so you get no compiler error, but your string doesn't contain what you expect.

Second line:  according to the reference of [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/),
you can replace a substring by another substring **based on the substring position**.
However, there is no version that makes a substitution, i.e. replace all occurences of a given substring by another one.

This doesn't exist in the standard library. It exists for example in the boost library, see [boost string algorithms](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/string_algo.html). The algorithm you are looking for is called replace_all.